# Stylus Interpolation in CSS "content"

Tags: stylus

I'm using Stylus' interpolation like so:

```
for num in (1..12)
    .foot:nth-of-type({num})
        left 8.33% * num
        &:after
            content \'{num}\' // ??? This isn't working
```

The part that's getting me is the `content` property. It's supposed to set to 1-12 respectively matching the `nth-of-type`. But no matter what I try it seems to be blank. Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that putting `num` in `()` fixes the issue:

`content \'(num)\'`